# Flexbox max-width 100%

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Estou estudando sobre flexbox e tentei montar uma estrutura com flex layout ao qual eu tenho um container que preenche toda a minha página, dentro deste container eu tenho dois elementos, uma sidebar posicionado a esquerda com altura de 100% e largura fixa e tenho também um content ao qual será responsável por conter o conteúdo da minha página, sendo que no entanto um dos meus conteúdos será uma área de notificação (notification) que terá altura fixa mais largura de 100% do meu content e dentro dessa área irei ter diversos cards que irá conter as mensagens propriamente.

O problema é que a minha notification está extrapolando a largura do meu content mesmo eu definindo a max-width para ela.

[Código no CodePen](https://codepen.io/zander-br/pen/LYGydYW)

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body,
#root {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
}

.sidebar {
  display: flex;
  background: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
}

.content {
  background: yellow;
  display: flex;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 15px;
  flex: 1;
}

.notification {
  display: flex;
  background: gray;
  overflow-x: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  align-items: center;
  /* Se eu coloco da forma abaixo funciona */
  /* max-width: 100px; */
  /* min-width: 100%; */
}

.card {
  height: 200px;
  min-height: 200px;
  min-width: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: green;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="sidebar"></div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="notification">
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: De uma olhada em como [inspecionar os elementos da página](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/css). E sobre [flex-box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) tem esse guia que eu uso bastante.

Comment: Cara eu não entendi direito o problema, vc tem uma imagem de como tem que ficar o layout?

Comment: Então @hugocsl eu preciso criar uma área que irão mostrar os meus cards um do lado do outro, e quando esses cards encher toda a minha área da minha notificação preciso que crie uma barra de rolagem horizontal para exibir todos os meus itens. Tipo assim [resultado esperado](https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/qY79hcc)

Answer (score -1):

Você pode adicionar a propriedade `flex-wrap: wrap` na classe `notification`:

```
.notification {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: flex;
  background: gray;
  overflow-x: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  align-items: center;  
}
```

O `flex-wrap` serve para indicar a forma como os itens serão apresentados dentro do elemento.

Ao definirmos o `flex-wrap` como `wrap` estamos dizendo que os itens serão agrupados em várias linhas, de cima para baixo.

Quando você não indica a forma de fazer o wrap, os itens serão disponibilizados em uma única linha contínua (por padrão). Por isso, os cards estavam fazendo o seu content "esticar" e ignorar a propriedade `width: 100%` do notification.

Comment: Obrigado Rafael pela sua resposta, mais assim o que eu preciso é que os meus `cards` fiquem um do lado do outro, e quando os cards preencher toda a largura da minha classe `notification` eu preciso que crie uma barra de rolagem horizontal e não quebrar linha.